# Insert into multiple rows in mysql (or JPA)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I want to insert something like

```
insert into person (person_name, person_city, person_contact) values ("nilesh", "pune", (1234567, 987654, 562917, 357181));
```

person_contact can be any in number.
Its giving error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

I have other way in ejb is -

```
for(Integer specializationId : specializationIds){

        Person person = new Person();
                person.setPersonName(personName);
                person.setPersonCity(personCIty);
                person.setPersonContact(personContact);
                em.persist(person);

            }
```

is there any other way to do this?

Comment: have you actually tested it? you won't get hurt doing so :)

Comment: i tested its giving me "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: you want to save more than one contact numbers in one column with comma separated values?

Comment: No, I want multiple entries to be added for each contact number (this will sound bad code but my scenario is different actually, I am just giving example here)

Comment: insert into person (person_name, person_city, person_contact) values ("nilesh", "pune", "1234567, 987654, 562917, 357181"); may work

Comment: this will insert all contact numbers in single field. I don't want it. I want multiple entries to be inserted

Comment: So you say you're using JPA, yet present no entity, no metadata, and no persistence code about how you hope to "insert" that. So please clarify what this has to do with JPA

Comment: Yes I am using jpa. my Entity is person. I can do this using for loop and having entityManager.persist() in loop. But I am just trying to get it without loop. (But I can use native query is it solves my problem)

Comment: Considered using a batch update?

Comment: Your "JPA code" doesn't quote the entity itself, it doesn't explain what is this "person_contact" field, whether it is 1-N etc. And if that is not a relation field then you need to seriously consider changing your "object model" (if you have one).

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables to hold data and use it in SQL query and then use for loop.

e.g.

```
for()
{
    String name = Get Name value;
    String city = Get City value;
    double number = Mobile Number;

    query = insert into tbl_name values(name,city,number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
insert into person (person_name, person_city, person_contact) values 
("nilesh", "pune", 1234567) , ("nilesh", "pune",987654) , ("nilesh", "pune",562917) , ("nilesh", "pune",357181);
```

Comment: I cant use this. My data is generating dynamically And number of contact number is not defined.

Comment: use a loop with the common name and city and based on no of person contant generate the insert string

Comment: which data do you mean? if you are trying inserting multiple data from some user input, you can use loop just as Kumar says, or generate your sql dynamically, so you still be able to insert multiple data on a single query

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach to add multiple rows in DB

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (**LOOP_UPTO_NUMBER_OF_PERSONS_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD**){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setPersonName(personName);
        person.setPersonCity(personCIty);
        person.setPersonContact(personContact);
        // add into list
        persons.add(person);
    }
    personRepository.saveAll(persons);
```

or if you already have a list of persons you can simply do using

```
    List<Person> persons = **PERSONS_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD**
    personRepository.saveAll(persons);
```